# transparent overlay background image CSS

Tags: css

I Have a background image full screen, but i want  a black overlay on it with a opacity of 0.7

This is my code:

```
body { 
  background:url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;}
```

How do i do this?

My html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>

    <!-- Basic Page Needs
  ================================================== -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>New Year Countdown</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  ================================================== -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!-- CSS
  ================================================== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


    <!-- Favicon
    ================================================== -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">


</head>
<body>


<div id="over">k</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The over has to be an opacity overlay.

Comment: I went through skeleton framework. It's nothing different but the fact is if you ar etrying to modify the css of a third party div ie a div maybe from skeletong framework try using the same style like `.transparent{
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5) !important;
}` as on the run they might be change with jquery . If being used :)

Answer (score 9):

Use a div and assign a class transparent covering entire body then use:

```
.transparent {
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

which will do the task.

Also go through: [w3 school image transparency and overlay](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_transparency.asp)

Comment: So id did this, but it still don't work. I use skeleton for my framework. Do you know what to do?

Comment: I have posted my html

Comment: here's a fiddle .. i wrongle went to 255 forgot will be 0 :) :P

Comment: That wasn't really the problem, i still see no change after I do the above

Answer (score 1):

You can also work it out using the following technique:

```
background-color: black; /* The shade of black that you want*/
background-blend-mode: multiply;
```